# AddThis e.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, addthis, typeerror

I'm using AddThis widget in a project, my page code fragment is

```
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="display: inline">
            <div id="iconemail">
                <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="iconprint">
                <a class="addthis_button_print"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": true };</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=*MY ID*"></script>
        </div>
```

the problem is that i keep getting 
Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function addthis_widget.js:1
The script is minimized so I can't do a thing about this particular error, the same code on JSFiddle works fine, any ideas what can cause this behaviour are appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict between AddThis and the version of MooTools you have on the site. Are you able to upgrade to a newer version of MooTools?

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely correct, updating MooTools solved the issue right away, thank you very much!